# How can we add the space between bars for multiple groups of bars in c3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 130],
            ['data3', 130]

        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
        width: 50,

    }
});
```

Here we have shown datas in three groups into data1,data2 and data3 but the graphs are attached without any spaces  like in images 
[image: bars without space between them.]

How can we add the space in between the bars?

Answer (score 9):

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 130],
            ['data3', 130]

        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
        space: 0.25
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is currently not in the https://c3js.org/reference.html documentation, and I was about to resort to svg manipulation, had I not found this answer. (The same `bar.space` setting also appears to be useful for getting overlapping bars, by specifying a negative value.)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @zohaib-ijaz's comment. I came up with:

```
d3.selectAll(".c3-target-nameofyourclass")
    .selectAll(".c3-bar")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-5, 0)");
```

to move the bars from column "nameofyourclass" 5 pixels to the left.

Answer (score 2):

here is the way in c3 to achieve what you want. you are not able to creat space between different columns as per my knowledge.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
      data: {
        columns: [
            ['barData', 30, 130, 130]
        ],
         type: 'bar'
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
        }
    },
    bar: {
        width: 50,
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
bar: {
    width: {
        ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
    }
```

Comment: keeping the width in this case does not solves  the problem in the case of upper code here datas are represented in three groups its not the same  data of individual group.

Comment: Inspect element bar and check what is it's `css class`. Let's say it is `bar` then apply style like .bar { padding-left: 5px;}

Comment: you are creating three different columns if you want to represent single data set  why not you represent it as ['data', 30,130,130]?